# Redirecting the input of two commands via pipe operator in Bash

Tags: bash, pipe, temporary-files

I have not learned Bash in a formal way so please do give me suggestions for a more descriptive question title.

Instead of creating a temporary file whose lifespan is limited to that of the command it is used by (in this case, `command`), as in:

```
zcat input.txt.gz > input.txt
command input.txt
rm input.txt
```

we can avoid it as follows:

```
zcat input.txt.gz | command -
```

Now my question is whether this is possible with two inputs.  I wish to avoid creating two temporary files, as in:

```
zcat input1.txt.gz > input1.txt
zcat input2.txt.gz > input2.txt
command input1.txt input2.txt
rm input1.txt input2.txt
```

I am guessing that the following solution can remove the need to create one of the two temporary files, as:

```
zcat input1.txt.gz > input1.txt
zcat input2.txt.gz | command input1.txt -
rm input1.txt
```

but I wonder if there is a way to completely avoid creating the temporary file.

I hope my question was clear enough.  Though I used `zcat` as an example, the solution I am looking for should be more general.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would in effect `zcat` both inputs into a single stream and then redirect that to `command`.  It would not work if `paste` were the command in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to combine the output of multiple commands into a single pipe, use a [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Subshells):

```
(cat file1.txt; cat file2.txt) | nl
```

If you want to use the output of a command as a filename for a command, use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Process_Substitution):

```
diff <(zcat file1.gz) <(zcat file2.gz)
```

Comment: I am not trying to combine the output of multiple commands, but that is a really neat trick I didn't know!  I want to do exactly `zcat input.txt.gz | command -` but with two inputs, each as a separate argument in place of where the filename would have been.

Comment: Then I think you want the second one, in your exact example `command <(zcat input1.txt.gz) <(zcat input2.txt.gz)`

Comment: Sorry, I had not properly tested your command.  Thank you, it works like a charm!  What nuances exist between the following two syntaxes: `zcat input1.txt.gz | command -` and `command <(zcat input1.txt.gz)`?

Comment: The nuances depend on what exactly `command` is. `zcat input1.txt.gz | command -` uses the stdin of `command`. The "-" argument can be interpreted by `command` however it sees fit. `command <(zcat input1.txt.gz)` has nothing to do with stdin at all, it uses other file descriptors.

Comment: The `command <(zcat input1.txt.gz)` syntax runs `zcat` with its output directed to a pipe, then passes a temporary name for that pipe to `command` -- it winds up running something like `command /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62`, where those fd's are the pipes from the `zcat` processes.

Answer (score 0):

Subshells might get you what you want:

```
command $(zcat input1.txt.gz) $(zcat input2.txt)
```

So long the stdout of the 2 subshells (above) make up arguments for 'command'

Comment: That prints the entire contents of the files into the argument list.  Try `command $(echo foo) $(echo bar)` and you'll see that.